# how to fetch nested object in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
How can i fetch nested object in elastic search ? 

{
            "_index": "userinfo",
            "_type": "userdetails",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": "2",
               "name": "Robert Mark",
               "age": 42,
               "email": "robert.mark@ceb.com",
               "userType": {
                  "id": "3",
                  "type": "End User"
               },
               "hobbies": [
                  {
                     "id": "3",
                     "description": "Writing Books"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "4",
                     "description": "Gardening"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
```

This is my json structure i want to fetch all the records where description under hobbies are "Gardening" .

I am new to elastic search please help me for this if any one knows .

"description": "Gardening"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "hobbies",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "hobbies.description": "Gardening"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

israelst is correct *if* you precreated a `nested` mapping type for your hobbies object. By default though, it uses `object` instead of `nested.

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "hobbies.description" : "Gardening"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the queries are practically the same and, in fact, my example is a subset of the nested version.

Comment: My Hobby Object is already mapped as type nested  but still your solution is not working                                                                                               @Field(type = FieldType.Nested) 
 private List<Hobby> hobbies;    anyway thanks for the answer.